# Call to Action Button - Resize Help

Tags: actions, code, buttons

I need help with resizing the "free quote" action button on my website. It is placed on the menu on the right top corner. I need to resize it to smaller size so that it fits the size with other text on the menu.

Link to the site: http://www.ninjacreativity.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much a WordPress questions as it is a simple CSS question, but adding this rule to your theme's CSS should make the button text the same size as the surrounding text.

```
.navbar .header-right a {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

If you also wanted to reduce the overall size of the box that surrounds the text, you could adjust the **padding** (currently set to `padding: 4px 12px 4px;` in the theme's CSS file).

```
.navbar .header-right a {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px 7px; // 2px padding on top and bottom, 7px on right and left
}
```

Further Reading: [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), [Padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).

Comment: It worked. The text inside the box is smaller now. I want to make the surround box/button small. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I have added more information related to the surrounding box.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot, Mark. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to mark my answer as the solution and/or upvote it if you're able.